# 2015 Escape Ford Sync error - What the heck is this error icon?

Tags: ford, electronics, fuse, fuse-panel

I have a 2015 Ford Escape with the non-touch Sync. After working sporadically for the past year or so, my Aux input/USB/Bluetooth have completely stopped working. If I press the "Media" button, it shows the 'error' icon below. Is that an icon of a fuse? No Sync-related items show in any menus anymore.

I tried **removing/reseating** both Sync-related fuses, even though they were not popped. (F67 and F85 under the glove box). I have **replaced** both fuses. I have **disconnected the battery** for several minutes to try to reset it. (Sync "Master reset" is not showing in any menu). I've tried **updating Sync firmware** with a USB stick, formatted properly, but nothing happens when I put it in the port. The LED on the USB stick lights up though, so at least I know it's getting power.

My trusted local mechanic won't touch Ford electronic systems since they're so problematic, and he pointed me to nearest dealership. After a complete transmission rebuild at < 40k, rust on the inside of the doors, and now this, I think this is my first and last Ford.

**Are there any more troubleshooting steps before I cough up big bucks at the Ford dealer?**

[image: Stupid error graphic with no text]

Comment: Stories of problem cars exist for every manufacturer, the trick is to avoid them :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After $105 in diagnostics at the Ford dealership, I was told that this indicates that the "Accessory Protocol Interface Module" (APIM) needs to be replaced. I was quoted $670 USD for replacement. Time to hit the scrapyard to see if I can find/re-program a replacement myself.